# In an interactive reports with regions A&B having separate update link columns, After Updating from Region B it doesnt return with updated data

Tags: oracle-apex

i am working in oracle apex 23.2 interactive reports with two separate regions i.e A and B both having update  links defined as columns. now when  click on the update link of  regin A and return after making changes, the selected region updates with the changes. but when i click on update  link of region B and doesnt refresh after making changes. If any one suggests where i am going wrong ?

I am asking a qestion related to APEX

Comment: how does this update link act? opens up a popup? if so, check your page processes to if there is a process called Close Dialog. if you check its setup you'll get what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very vague description but I think you have the following question: A page has 2 regions of type IR. Each of the IR reports have a link to a form page. When editing a record in the first IR and then saving it and closing the form the report refreshes. When editing a record in the second IR and then saving it and closing the form the report does not refresh.

The refresh is triggered by a dynamic action on dialog close. That dynamic action is bound to the region that fires the dialog and has a true action of "refresh" to refresh the region. If you have more regions, you'll need a dynamic action per region.

I created a page (pg 219) of type "Interactive report" with an IR (region "Emp IR") on table EMP and a form (pg 220). When I click the "Apply Changes" button in the form, the form closes and the Emp IR region on the report page refreshes.

Now I added a 2nd region on page 219 of type Interactive Report on table DEPT. Region is called "Dept IR". The "Edit" link points to a form on DEPT (pg 221).  Then I added a dynamic action on pg 219. The screenshots are for the 2nd dynamic action

[image]

With a true action of type "Refresh" to refresh "Dept IR"

[image]

Both reports now refresh after editing a record. You need a "Dialog Closed" dynamic action **per report** for the refresh.